# Pylance doesn't show suggestions for not-yet-imported definitions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

According to the [Pylance extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance), I should be able to write "g" in my python code, and then Pylance should suggest that I import the `gc` module (see screenshot below, or [the gif from the docs itself](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/raw/prerelease/images/all-features.gif)). But I can't get this to work on my system.

This is what I expect to happen (screenshot from Pylance extension page):

[image: expected]

This is what happens on my system:

[image: actual]

Can someone please help me understand why Pylance isn't working as advertised on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wager you need to put the following in your user settings.json or workspace `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
`"python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true`
```

(The default value of the setting if not specified is `false`)

You may also be interested in the related `python.analysis.importFormat` ("*defines the default format for import module*") and `python.analysis.autoImportUserSymbols` ("*Offer user symbols in auto-import completions*") settings.